# openCL glGetProgramInfo causing Core Foundation crash

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, opencl

I am writing a C++ command line program in XCode (6.4) on OSX Yosemite (10.10.4). I am using Apple's openCL framework and am trying to save my openCL binaries to disk.

First I create my program from source and build as follows:

```
cl_int err;
cl_program result = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, numFiles, (const char **)sourceStrings, NULL, &err);
ErrorManager::CheckError(err, "Failed to create a compute program");

err = clBuildProgram(result, deviceCount, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);
ErrorManager::CheckError(err, "Failed to build program");
```

The above code works fine and I can launch my kernels without any error.

Then I try to access the binary sizes...

```
size_t *programBinarySizes = new size_t[deviceCount];
err = clGetProgramInfo(result, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, sizeof(size_t) * deviceCount, programBinarySizes, NULL);
```

However this call to clGetProgramInfo causes Xcode to throw an EXC_BREAKPOINT that has the following output:

```
CoreFoundation`__CFTypeCollectionRetain:
0x7fff8e2c2480 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
0x7fff8e2c2481 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x7fff8e2c2484 <+4>:   pushq  %r14
0x7fff8e2c2486 <+6>:   pushq  %rbx
0x7fff8e2c2487 <+7>:   movq   %rsi, %rbx
0x7fff8e2c248a <+10>:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x7fff8e2c248d <+13>:  je     0x7fff8e2c25ae            ; <+302>
0x7fff8e2c2493 <+19>:  cmpb   $0x0, -0x17f41f28(%rip)   ; __CFDeallocateZombies
0x7fff8e2c249a <+26>:  je     0x7fff8e2c257c            ; <+252>
0x7fff8e2c24a0 <+32>:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x7fff8e2c24a3 <+35>:  je     0x7fff8e2c24b5            ; <+53>
0x7fff8e2c24a5 <+37>:  leaq   -0x17f917cc(%rip), %rax   ; kCFAllocatorSystemDefault
0x7fff8e2c24ac <+44>:  cmpq   %rdi, (%rax)
0x7fff8e2c24af <+47>:  jne    0x7fff8e2c257c            ; <+252>
0x7fff8e2c24b5 <+53>:  testb  $0x1, %bl
0x7fff8e2c24b8 <+56>:  je     0x7fff8e2c24e4            ; <+100>
0x7fff8e2c24ba <+58>:  movl   %ebx, %eax
0x7fff8e2c24bc <+60>:  shrl   %eax
0x7fff8e2c24be <+62>:  andl   $0x7, %eax
0x7fff8e2c24c1 <+65>:  cmpl   $0x6, %eax
0x7fff8e2c24c4 <+68>:  ja     0x7fff8e2c259c            ; <+284>
0x7fff8e2c24ca <+74>:  leaq   0xef(%rip), %rcx          ; <+320>
0x7fff8e2c24d1 <+81>:  movslq (%rcx,%rax,4), %rax
0x7fff8e2c24d5 <+85>:  addq   %rcx, %rax
0x7fff8e2c24d8 <+88>:  jmpq   *%rax
0x7fff8e2c24da <+90>:  callq  0x7fff8e2df7b0            ; CFStringGetTypeID
0x7fff8e2c24df <+95>:  jmp    0x7fff8e2c2594            ; <+276>
0x7fff8e2c24e4 <+100>: movl   0x8(%rbx), %eax
0x7fff8e2c24e7 <+103>: shrl   $0x8, %eax
0x7fff8e2c24ea <+106>: andl   $0x3ff, %eax
0x7fff8e2c24ef <+111>: movq   (%rbx), %rcx
0x7fff8e2c24f2 <+114>: testq  %rcx, %rcx
0x7fff8e2c24f5 <+117>: je     0x7fff8e2c2522            ; <+162>
0x7fff8e2c24f7 <+119>: cmpq   -0x17f41f96(%rip), %rcx   ; __CFConstantStringClassReferencePtr
0x7fff8e2c24fe <+126>: je     0x7fff8e2c2522            ; <+162>
0x7fff8e2c2500 <+128>: leaq   -0x17f43fa7(%rip), %rdx   ; __CFRuntimeObjCClassTable
0x7fff8e2c2507 <+135>: movq   (%rdx,%rax,8), %r14
0x7fff8e2c250b <+139>: cmpq   %r14, %rcx
0x7fff8e2c250e <+142>: je     0x7fff8e2c2522            ; <+162>
0x7fff8e2c2510 <+144>: testb  $0x1, %cl
0x7fff8e2c2513 <+147>: je     0x7fff8e2c2594            ; <+276>
0x7fff8e2c2515 <+149>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x7fff8e2c2518 <+152>: callq  0x7fff8e481b6a            ; symbol stub for: object_getClass
0x7fff8e2c251d <+157>: cmpq   %r14, %rax
0x7fff8e2c2520 <+160>: jne    0x7fff8e2c2594            ; <+276>
0x7fff8e2c2522 <+162>: callq  0x7fff8e481aaa            ; symbol stub for: objc_collectableZone
0x7fff8e2c2527 <+167>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x7fff8e2c252a <+170>: movq   %rbx, %rsi
0x7fff8e2c252d <+173>: callq  0x7fff8e481594            ; symbol stub for: auto_zone_is_valid_pointer
0x7fff8e2c2532 <+178>: testl  %eax, %eax
0x7fff8e2c2534 <+180>: je     0x7fff8e2c255b            ; <+219>
0x7fff8e2c2536 <+182>: movl   0x8(%rbx), %eax
0x7fff8e2c2539 <+185>: shrl   $0x8, %eax
0x7fff8e2c253c <+188>: andl   $0x3ff, %eax
0x7fff8e2c2541 <+193>: leaq   -0x17f45ff8(%rip), %rcx   ; __CFRuntimeClassTable
0x7fff8e2c2548 <+200>: movq   (%rcx,%rax,8), %rax
0x7fff8e2c254c <+204>: testb  $0x4, (%rax)
0x7fff8e2c254f <+207>: je     0x7fff8e2c2594            ; <+276>
0x7fff8e2c2551 <+209>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x7fff8e2c2554 <+212>: callq  0x7fff8e2bf500            ; CFRetain
0x7fff8e2c2559 <+217>: jmp    0x7fff8e2c2594            ; <+276>
0x7fff8e2c255b <+219>: cmpl   $0x0, 0xc(%rbx)
0x7fff8e2c255f <+223>: je     0x7fff8e2c2594            ; <+276>
0x7fff8e2c2561 <+225>: leaq   -0x17f72248(%rip), %rsi   ; @"storing a non-GC object %p in a GC collection, break on CFCollection_non_gc_storage_error to debug."
0x7fff8e2c2568 <+232>: movl   $0x4, %edi
0x7fff8e2c256d <+237>: xorl   %eax, %eax
0x7fff8e2c256f <+239>: movq   %rbx, %rdx
0x7fff8e2c2572 <+242>: callq  0x7fff8e3b61e0            ; CFLog
0x7fff8e2c2577 <+247>: callq  0x7fff8e3c3290            ; CFCollection_non_gc_storage_error
0x7fff8e2c257c <+252>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x7fff8e2c257f <+255>: popq   %rbx
0x7fff8e2c2580 <+256>: popq   %r14
0x7fff8e2c2582 <+258>: popq   %rbp
0x7fff8e2c2583 <+259>: jmp    0x7fff8e2bf500            ; CFRetain
0x7fff8e2c2588 <+264>: callq  0x7fff8e2df7f0            ; CFNumberGetTypeID
0x7fff8e2c258d <+269>: jmp    0x7fff8e2c2594            ; <+276>
0x7fff8e2c258f <+271>: callq  0x7fff8e2df850            ; CFDateGetTypeID
0x7fff8e2c2594 <+276>: movq   %rbx, %rax
0x7fff8e2c2597 <+279>: popq   %rbx
0x7fff8e2c2598 <+280>: popq   %r14
0x7fff8e2c259a <+282>: popq   %rbp
0x7fff8e2c259b <+283>: retq   
0x7fff8e2c259c <+284>: int3   
0x7fff8e2c259d <+285>: callq  0x7fff8e482020            ; symbol stub for: getpid
0x7fff8e2c25a2 <+290>: movl   $0x9, %esi
0x7fff8e2c25a7 <+295>: movl   %eax, %edi
0x7fff8e2c25a9 <+297>: callq  0x7fff8e482080            ; symbol stub for: kill
0x7fff8e2c25ae <+302>: leaq   0x36325e(%rip), %rax      ; "*** __CFTypeCollectionRetain() called with NULL; likely a collection has been corrupted ***"
0x7fff8e2c25b5 <+309>: movq   %rax, -0x17f460c4(%rip)   ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x7fff8e2c25bc <+316>: int3   
->  0x7fff8e2c25bd <+317>: jmp    0x7fff8e2c259d            ; <+285>
0x7fff8e2c25bf <+319>: nop
```

This exception doesn't get thrown if I call clGetProgramInfo with a param name other than CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES.

I cannot figure out the reason why I'm getting this exception. It's puzzling because I'm writing a C++ program, not an ObjC or Swift one, so I don't see why I would be getting any errors related to Core Foundation or retain counts.

My only guess is maybe there is some build settings option that I have set incorrectly that is causing my program to think this is an objc environment but that seems unlikely.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is this in Objective-C++? If you replace `size_t *programBinarySizes = new size_t[deviceCount];` with `size_t programBinarySizes[100]` (where 100 is an arbitrary large number), do you get the same result?

Comment: No it is regular C++ / .cpp files. I've found that the issue only happens if I call clBuildProgram on a subset of the devices associated with the programs context and not all the devices in the context. This is still weird because according to the Khronos docs, the program binary size for a program's device that hasn't been built should just be zero but instead I get an runtime error.